# NullPointerException in Scanner when reading a Serializable Object from File

Tags: java, exception, file-io, nullpointerexception

I am trying to edit an array of objects after reading them by using Serializable.
The code works fine for new instance of my object but gives a NullPointer exception when I try to edit the object read from file.

```
public class ShoppingCenter implements Serializable{

// I cant write to file without transient
transient Scanner scan=new  Scanner (System.in);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757692L;


//This is the edit details method which will be used to modify the details
public void editDetails()
{
 System.out.println("The details are as follows:");
    System.out.println("*Name is "+ name);
    System.out.println("\t(1-Edit 2-Continue)");

    // *******This is where it gives the exception********
    if (scan.nextInt()==1)
    {System.out.println("\t Write the new value..");
        name=scan.next(); 
    System.out.println("Done..");}

    System.out.println("*Location is "+ location);
    System.out.println("\t(1-Edit 2-Continue)");
    if (scan.nextInt()==1)
    {System.out.println("\t Write the new value..");
        location=scan.next(); 
    System.out.println("Done..");}
}
```

This is the stack Trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ShoppingCenter.editDetails(ShoppingCenter.java:40)
at Part3Main.searchObject(Part3Main.java:99)
at Part3Main.init(Part3Main.java:130)
at Part3Main.main(Part3Main.java:189)
```

Here is my driver.

```
       public void init(){
       readFile("shoppingCenter");
        }

        public void readFile(String name){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(name);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        sc = (ShoppingCenter[]) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("The Object  was succesfully read from the file");
        //System.out.println(sc[1].toString());
        //System.out.println(sc.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A little help would be really appreciated.. Thanks ..

Comment: Transient objects aren't deserialized, so on deserialization the scan field of ShoppingCenter will be null. Can't you create scan in editDetails()?

Comment: It Worked....Thanks a lot.. !!!!